# c# leftpad or rightpad to achieve certain format

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i am using unity but the problem is more towards c#.

i was given a textbox (or something similar) by my colleague(designer).
imagine box 1 is the header and box 2 is the one he gave me(the one i need to return the string to).

[image: Image Reference]

thus, i create a function to return a string from the database for the content of box 2.
i have managed to create some sort of string as such below:

```
08/12/2020  
Tom  
Sarah  
Holden  
Jimmy
```

but i am struggling to create the preferred format which is

```
08/12/2020     Tom  
               Sarah  
               Holden  
               Jimmy
```

i tried to used rightpad such like `dateVal.PadRight(20, ' ');`

but how can i apply that to the next line without the date?

should i use leftpad as well?

Edit: I'm a newbie in Unity~~

Comment: Is this going to be a monospaced font? Because if not, good luck on outlining this with spaces. Why did your coworker decide on this approach? Why don't they loop over records and print the appropriate strings instead?

Comment: Can't you put this into 4 individual text fields instead?

Comment: @CodeCaster bad luck to me then. it was supposed to be an interface for a trainer to train many students with different dates. 1 day 4 students, another day could be 5

Comment: @derHugo i want to use that idea as well but there are more than one date. its like one to many relationships. one date with a number of students. and all of that in one interface.

Comment: You could just use two textboxes aligned next to each other, and print the date in one, and the names in the other.

Comment: Well create a prefab of the box with a field for the data and a field for the students .. then spawn as many boxes as there are dates and fill both fields with the according data ... You could even go one step further and have a prefab for a student's field and then dynamically spawn as many as needed and scale the box dynamically ...

Comment: @derHugo ive thought of that actually but i forgot to say im a newbie so i sought for a simpler solution. btw i think this is the best way to do it maybe if i have more time and knowledge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oh my.. i forgot about this question. btw i used the method mentioned by @CodeCaster

> use two textboxes aligned next to each other, and print the date in one, and
> the names in the other

and put it inside a scrolling rectangle..

Answer (score -1):

Hi please try the function below, this is assuming that the source value is a string with newline as a delimeter.

```
 public static string FormatSource(string source)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        var values = source.Split(Environment.NewLine);
        DateTime dateValue;
        int padCount = 0;
        foreach(var value in values)
        {
            if(DateTime.TryParseExact(value,"mm/dd/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
    System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out dateValue))
            {
                padCount = 10;
                sb.Append(value);
            }
            else
            {
                sb.Append(value.PadLeft(padCount) + Environment.NewLine);
                padCount = 20;
            }
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
```